# How do I set the entered subfolder as root?

Tags: apache, xampp

I have setup VirtualHost and it works good when I use the domain (ex. www.website_1.se). The problem is that the DocumentRoot that is set for the VirtualHost is not applied when I visit the website through localhost (ex. localhost/website_1.se).

My root folder looks like this:

website_1.se, website_2.se, website_3.se

And my conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@website_1.se
    ServerName website_1.se
    ServerAlias www.website_1.se
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/website_1.se"
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside website_1.se, I have html-files with src attributes, some of them starts with '/', which refers to the root.

So if I have a src="/images/file.jpg" inside the index file of "website_1.se", and enter "localhost/website_1.se, Apache will try to load that image from localhost/images/file.jpg instead of localhost/website_1.se/images/file.jpg

So my question is. How can I use '/' in paths, so that it works the same way for both localhost and VirtualHost (domain)?

**EDIT (I ask the question again, better and clearer this time hopefully.)**

I need to be able to host multiple websites on my apache server.
I have managed to do it with the help of vhost.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site_1.se
    ServerAlias www.site_1.se
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site_1.se"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site_2.se
    ServerAlias www.site_2.se
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site_2.se"
</VirtualHost>
```

So when I enter www.site_1.se I get to localhost(htdocs)/site_1.se. And when I enter www.site_2.se I get to localhost(htdocs)/site_2.se and so on. Perfect, that's the point.

Now here is the problem. These folders (site_1.se & site_2.se) contains html-files, and in these files I have links with addresses that starts with '/', which refers to the root.

So for example if have: `<img src="/images/file.png">`
inside a html-file in site_1.se, Apache tries to locate the image in:

localhost/site_1.se/images/file.png (if entering www.site_1.se)

or

localhost/images/file.png (if entering localhost/site_1.se)

So this obviously becomes a problem when developing in localhost and using '/' at the beginning of paths. Because when you then visit the page from the domain name, the links are wrong.
So I'm wondering how can I set up apache, so I can specify paths starting with '/', and get the same root no matter how I visit the site?

Comment: I already have this: `<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>` ... because through localhost I still need to access the sites like this: localhost/website_1, localhost/website_2 and so on.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

for localhost configuration listen on different ports so as to distinguish between the different sites. You need to tell Apache to listen on those ports also.

```
Listen 80
Listen 81

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site_1.se"
    Require all granted
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site_2.se"
    Require all granted
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I doesn't work that way for all subfolders. If I visit localhost/website_1.se, then the root should be localhost/website_1.se. But if I visit localhost/website_2.se the root should be localhost/website_2.se and so on

Comment: you do not need virtual hosts to achieve that on localhost

Comment: So what do I need? And also, dont forget that www.website_1.se must go too localhost/website_1.se and www.website_2.se must go to localhost/website_2.se. How else achive this without vhost? :)

Comment: what folder name does localhost currently point to on your computer ?

Comment: create folder 'website_1.se' in htdocs folder, create folder 'website_2.se' in htdocs folder, job done

Comment: Thank you Mike, but you don't seem to understand my question

Comment: Your question essentially boils down to if you specify a image directory path on localhost that does not exist then how do you get apache to open a different directory path without altering the html code in your files.  Simple answer is that you should have the same folder structure on your localhost as your live server.  But if for some mind boggling reason you did not want to do that you could create Apache rewrite rules on the localhost.

Comment: Why are you not copying the images folder into each of the site folders ?

Comment: Images folder is already in each of the site folders, and that's where I want to get the images from. And that's where apache will look for the images IF visiting the site using the domain name because the root is set to each site/folder in vhost